Why both Ddim and Fdim resolve to Am nicely even though they are not in the same key?
I've been playing some chords and accidentally discovered that Ddim (triad, not dim7) transitions/resolves to Am quite nicely. That I did not expect that because I know they are not in the same key. After listening to other diminished chords resolving to Am chord I found that it's not the only dim chord that nicely resolves to Am.
Among Adim-Gdim chords (roots from Am scale), three chords resolve to Am nicely: Bdim (in the Am key, so it is expected), Ddim, Fdim.
I would expect Bdim to be the best (it is in the key with Am), but, subjectively, Fdim resolves to Am even better.
I asked another person, which of the 6 transitions sound best, and they identified exactly those 3 I have identified, with Fdim resolving to Am the best.
I have just started learning music theory, so I am sorry if the answer is obvious and I have just overlooked some lessons.
So why the chords Ddim and Fdim resolve to Am so nicely, even though they are not in the same key (A minor) ?

Please be aware that just because a note in a piece isn't 'in the key' (as in in the scale), doesn't preclude it from being in a chord in that piece - or even in the melody somewhere. We get an awful lot of questions which are based on that premise! And, with minors, there's such a lot of extra notes to choose from that are 'in the key'.

Summary: The presence of G#/Ab — the leading tone in A minor — is the determining element.

First, recognize that Ddim7 and Fdim7 are enharmonically equivalent. That is, they contain the same pitches, spelled differently: D=Ebb, F, Ab, Cb.
Next, notice that Ab = G#, which is the leading tone — the raised seventh degree — of the A minor scale.
The diminished (seventh) chord built on the raised seventh degree in minor is a standard chord when composing in a minor key.
Thus, Ddim7, Fdim7, G#dim7, and Bdim7 are all the same (enharmonically equivalent) chord.

Note, all of this is about diminished sevenths; diminished triads would change things.

I think you mean dim7 in the last sentence. But then again, in practice, "dim" is often written when "dim7" is actually meant. Or dim7 is played even if dim was written and/or meant.

I first was confused, because Fdim and Ddim triads do not have the same set of pitches (D is not in Fdim and B is not in Ddim). After reading the comments the answer became clear. Indeed, when discussing dim7 chord, Fdim and Ddim are  invertions of one another. However, in my question I actually meant triads, not seventh chords. Does the answer apply to triads as well, because they contain the leading note of Amin (Ab) ?

@g00dds Yes. The presence of Ab/G# is the key.

Note that Ddim and Fdim can both be treated as respelled versions of G#dim7 with a note missing (notably not the G# or the chord's 7th, the F).
